# SolverAdd Does not work

Tags: vba, solver

The solverAdd statement in my VBA code does not work. 
it goes like this:

```
SolverReset
SolverOkDialog SetCell:=Range("$C$98"), MaxMinVal:=1, ByChange:=Range("$L$2:$L$85"), Engine:=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
SolverAdd CellRef:=Range("$L$2", "$L$" & cut_point), Relation:=3, FormulaText:="$D$96"
SolverAdd CellRef:=Range("$L$2:$L$85"), Relation:=5
SolverAdd CellRef:=Range("$D$95"), Relation:=1, FormulaText:="$C$95"
SolverSolve UserFinish:=True
SolverFinish KeepFinal:=1
SolverReset
```

But when implementing, the solver windows in excel always pops out and asks me to enter the constraints.

Truly appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

`SolverReset` does just that: resets everything.
So delete the second `SolverReset` from your code.
HTH